# Calculate width of each table column based on the number of columns

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have a table with x number of columns and the table has a fixed width.

```
<colgroup>
    <col width="20%" />
    <col width="20%" />
    <col width="20%" />
    <col width="20%" />
    <col width="20%" />
</colgroup>
```

I want the width of each column to be based on the number of columns. If 4 columns the width to be 25%, if 3 = 33% if 2 = 50%

Is there any way to do this without JavasScript?

Comment: If its a table of data, use a table. If not, use `display: table-cell`, there is currently no other way

Comment: Please elaborate your question , cause if we define specific width of the table, the columns distribute themselves equal amount of width in the table.

Comment: @ameyarote true, but only for some browsers, for Firefox on Mac, if you don't specify a width of the column, the columns are distributed 100% of the total width, but with different (not equal) widths.

Comment: @FlorescuAdrian - Can you tell me what exactly You are trying to do..? 
with more details and some cases, CSS could help U.>! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without javascript? No, you couldn't assign the columns the width values without using javascript.

HTML/CSS are for building the framework & styling a site, not for doing maths.

Also the use of percentages is used for when you don't know the fixed width of the container of the table, unless you are certain that the content is the same width then you could end up with table rows becoming very tall as you are squashing content into the 5 'fixed' width columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify which programming language you are using.

If you are using php..,

if the total number of column is `$x`

in the loop you have to set

```
<col width="<?php echo 100/$x; ?>" />
```